# Changing elements style property changes stored element style property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the convoluted question.

Why does this:

```
function captureEl(el) {
  var elInt     = document.getElementById(el),           // element
      elBottom  = elInt.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;  // px distance from top of page to bottom of element

  console.log(elBottom);
  console.log(elInt);

  console.log(elBottom);

  var newEl = document.getElementById(el);

  console.log(newEl.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);

  console.log(newEl);

  elInt.style.bottom = '300px';

}
```

Yield output like this:

```
711
<header id=​"header" style=​"bottom:​ 300px;​">​…​</header>​
711
711
<header id=​"header" style=​"bottom:​ 300px;​">​…​</header>​
```

I understand that the getBoundingClientRect().bottom and style property are different numbers, what I don't understand is why changing the style property effects a value I stored previously.

It seems like the first console entry shouldn't have the CSS property appended to it.

Edit:

HTML:

```
<header id="header">
   <div class="container">...</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(17,17,17,0.95);
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  transition: bottom 1s linear;
}
```

Edit 2:

So setting a variable of the computed style does the same thing.

```
function captureEl(el) {
  var elInt     = document.getElementById(el),            // element
      elBottom  = elInt.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,   
      elStyle   = window.getComputedStyle(elInt);

  console.log(elStyle);

  console.log('---');

  var newEl = document.getElementById(el);

  newEl.style.bottom = '300px';

  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(newEl));

  console.log('---');

  elInt.style.bottom = '300px';

  console.log(elStyle);

}
```

Computed output for the 3 logs shows bottom of 300px

Comment: _"bottom. A float. The Y-coordinate, relative to the viewport origin (0,0), of the bottom of the rectangle box."_ See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect

Comment: @evolutionxbox but why is the css property logged as 300px, before I even set the property?

Comment: Provide whole code - css and html.

Comment: ~It's likely you have some JS elsewhere which is setting it.~ *Edit:* OP is right. The bottom property is being set inside the provided function.